# Errors on startup

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, startup, thinkpad, error-handling

I'm running a Lenovo ThinkPad L390 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit GNOME version 3.36.2, and am receiving the following errors on startup:

```
In: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory 
/dev/mapper/local-root: clean, 297446/1831424 files, 5113581/7323648 blocks
[    3.632145] I2C multi instantiate pseudo device driver INT3515:03: IRQ index
[FAILED] Failed to listen on SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[FAILED] Failed to listen on SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[FAILED] Failed to listen on SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
[FAILED] Failed to listen on SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
```

Is there any way to fix this? 
[image]

Comment: Have you installed SSSD daemon ? You can boot to the emergency mode then temporarily disable the service via "systemctl disable sssd " . You can boot into the emergency mode via pressing "E" in the grub menu to open the config editor and put a "1" at the end of the line beginning with the "linux" command to boot into runlevel 1 . Login as root and disable the service SSSD.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I did as advised but it deleted my user account. Why is that? Is there a way to undo it?

Comment: [SSSD](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd) is not installed by default. How did you get there? Can you now login as root and backup your /home and create a new user ? I haven't used sssd before but I just suggested to disable it via systemd because it's a systemd service. Sorry , I didn't know it can cause such problems.